# Autoincrement dependent of other field

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird

What is the best way to get an autoincrement "counter" thath depends of other field?.

Imagine this table

```
CUSTOMER - COUNTER
1 - 1
1 - 2
1 - 3
2 - 1
2 - 2
```

I need Counter increments 1 every record I add for every customer.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Create additional table to hold counters for every customer:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_counter
(
  customer_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  counter      INTEGER NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
)
```

Use following procedure to obtain next counter number for given customer:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_customer_counter (customer_id INTEGER)
  RETURNS (counter INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(counter) FROM customer_counter
  WHERE customer_id = :customer_id
  INTO :counter;

  counter = COALESCE(:counter, 0);

  EXECUTE STATEMENT 
    'INSERT INTO customer_counter (customer_id, counter) ' ||
    'VALUES (' || :customer_id || ', 1)'
    WITH AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION;
END
```

See how we use sum and insert delta values instead of updating single record. Thus we prevent deadlocks.

On regular basis we need to clear counter table by merging delta records into one with a total value:

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_disconnect_database
  ACTIVE
  ON DISCONNECT
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE sm          INTEGER;
  DECLARE VARIABLE cnt         INTEGER;
  DECLARE VARIABLE customer_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR
    SELECT customer_id, SUM(counter), COUNT(counter)
    FROM customer_counter
    GROUP BY customer_id
    INTO :customer_id, :sm, :cnt
  DO BEGIN
    IF (:cnt > 1) THEN
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM customer_counter WHERE customer_id = :customer_id;
      INSERT INTO customer_counter (customer_id, counter)
        VALUES (:customer_id, :sm);
      WHEN ANY DO
      BEGIN
      END
    END
  END
END
```

Comment: I think I don't explained it correctly, sorry, but your answer will help me to another thing. The idea is, If I add a new record in the table, for customer 1, the counter value must be 4, but if it is for customer 2, the counter value must be 3. The idea is for example to assign an order field to the records of the detail of a bill. All the detail of the bills is in one table, and the counter value, must be autoincrement for each ID bill group. I hope I explained better now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to really tell what you exactly want of what you have given, but I assume you want to loop through each X field and it's Y sub-field, use it for a counter, or whatever else.

```
<?php
$x = array("customer1","customer2","customer3");
$y = array("name","address","phone");

$counter;

foreach($x as $eachX):
    $counter  = 1;
    foreach($y as $eachY):
        //do stuff here
        $counter++;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this stored procedure will be ok!

```
create procedure New_Procedure
returns (
o_customer integer,
o_counter integer)
as

declare variable v_oldcostomer integer;
begin

for select customer
 from customers
 order by 1
 into o_customer
 do begin
 if (v_oldcostomer is null or (v_oldcostomer is not null and v_oldcostomer <> o_customer) ) then
    o_counter = 0;

 o_counter = o_counter + 1;
 v_oldcostomer = o_customer;
 suspend;
 end
end
```